# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'language')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, codemirror

I am very new to Vue and JavaScript, so I imagine this is a really simple fix.
There are similar posts on here, but those solutions I implemented did not fix the problem.

I was able to utilize the CodeMirror library to get a codeboard, as well as an HTML dropdown with languages to select (without functioning).

From there, given the selected language in the dropdown, I was trying to update the language field, based on some examples I've seen of others implementing CodeMirror.

Any idea of what is going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
import { Codemirror } from "vue-codemirror";
import { javascript } from "@codemirror/lang-javascript";
import { python } from "@codemirror/lang-python";
import { oneDark } from "@codemirror/theme-one-dark";
import { reactive, computed } from "vue";

const themes = { oneDark };
const languages = {
  javascript: javascript(),
  python: python(),
};

const state = reactive({
  language: "python",
  theme: "oneDark",
});

const extensions = computed(() => {
  const result = [];
  result.push(languages[state.language]);
  if (themes[state.theme]) {
    result.push(themes[state.theme]);
  }
  return result;
});

export default {
  components: {
    Codemirror,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      extensions,
      log: console.log,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="toolbar">
    <pre class="state">{{ state }}</pre>
    <div class="config">
      <p>
        <label for="language">language:</label>
        <select name="language" id="language" v-model="state.language">
          <option
            :value="option"
            :key="option"
            v-for="option in ['python', 'javascript']"
          >
            {{ option }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <codemirror
    v-model="code"
    placeholder=""
    :style="{ height: '400px' }"
    :autofocus="true"
    :indent-with-tab="true"
    :tab-size="2"
    :extensions="extensions"
    @ready="log('ready', $event)"
    @change="log('change', $event)"
    @focus="log('focus', $event)"
    @blur="log('blur', $event)"
  />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your state and computed property to setup function:

```
export default {
  components: {
    Codemirror,
  },
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      language: "python",
      theme: "oneDark",
    });

    const extensions = computed(() => {
      const result = [];
      result.push(languages[state.language]);
      if (themes[state.theme]) {
        result.push(themes[state.theme]);
      }
      return result;
    });
    return {
      extensions, state,
      log: console.log,
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It was a matter of adding the state argument when returning, like in the snippet above.